# Why is there no "Mario Bunge" entry in the SEP? Where could I find a valuable presentation of Mario Bunge's philosophy?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, reference-request, formal-theory

I only have a rudimentary knowledge of Mario Bunge's philosophy.

But what I've read in the Ontology part of his *Treatise of basic philosophy* seems much promising.

I'm astonished that Bunge is not more frequently referred to.

Is it because of the technical complexity of his discourse ( that makes use of set theoretic and algebraic concepts)?

Or rather, is it because his attempt at using such concepts in philosophy is not considered as serious?

Is there any "bungeian" philosopher on this site that could indicate a reference
allowing to enter more easily into Bunge's philosophy?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe useful Mario Bunge, [Between Two Worlds : Memoirs of a Philosopher-Scientist (Springer, 2016)](https://books.google.it/books?id=i54YDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: There is also no entry on Kripke. There can be many reasons why there is no entry (yet) and nobody except maybe the people on the editorial board can tell you why. See also their [policies](https://plato.stanford.edu/info.html#policies).

Comment: You may already have this book:  PDF http://www.rosenfels.org/Mario_Bunge_-_Matter_and_Mind_-_A_Philosophical_Inquiry_(Springer,_2010).pdf ; PDF https://www.erudit.org/fr/revues/philoso/2010-v37-n2-philoso3970/045191ar.pdf

Comment: Appraisal of his philosophy of mathematics from one philosopher:  https://philarchive.org/archive/MARMBP  As to why there is no SEP article, maybe it's because there is so much to cover. He seems to have the most complete contemporary philosophy of anyone that I am aware of.

Comment: Ontology website:  https://www.ontology.co/#maincontent ; he has an entry here:  The Scientific Philosophy of Mario Bunge https://www.ontology.co/ontologists.htm

Answer (score 3):

There are two questions here (rephrased): "Where can I find an accessible introduction to Bunge's philosophy?" and "Why is Bunge not more frequently referred to?"

Let's start with the first question, which can be answered quickly. A good introduction to Bunge's work, similar to what you would find in an encyclopedia article, is the introduction by Michael R. Matthews, "Mario Bunge: An Introduction to His Life, Work and Achievements", in the 2019 edited collection *Mario Bunge: A Centenary Festschrift*. That book also presents a wide variety of chapters by different authors on various aspects of Bunge's work. If you want to read something in Bunge's own words, I found his 2006 book *Chasing Reality: Strife Over Realism* to be a good overview of his philosophy; his 2012 book *Evaluating Philosophies* is a good summary of his judgment of other philosophies; and his 2001 edited collection *Scientific Realism: Selected Essays of Mario Bunge* is a good selection of essays. His work developed over time, so when reading his work from earlier decades it's important to keep in mind that he modified some details later.

Now to the second question: Why is Bunge not more frequently referred to?

Bunge's total citation count in Google Scholar is enormous (today it is 60293, h-index 83, i10-index 335), and some sources (for example, the introduction to the 2019 book *Mario Bunge: A Centenary Festschrift*) mention that Bunge is ranked in something called the "Science Hall of Fame", which is a dataset of authors based on something like a citation count, so I would say that Bunge is referred to frequently enough. The prolific philosopher Nicholas Rescher said: "Mario Bunge has over the years established himself as the prime exponent of a scientifically informed philosophy of man, society, and nature."

But you might also be wondering why Bunge's work has not generated a scholarly industry of commentary, the way that there are whole scholarly journals devoted to the work of individual philosophers, such as the journals *Arendt Studies*, *Augustinian Studies*, *Berkeley Studies*, *Deleuze and Guattari Studies*, *Derrida Today*, *Hegel-Jahrbuch*, *Heidegger Studies*, *Hume Studies*, *Kant-Studien*, *Levinas Studies*, *The Lonergan Review*, *New Nietzsche Studies*, *Sartre Studies International*, *Studia Leibnitiana*, and so on (just to pick some journal titles that are listed in Wikipedia)?

Bunge himself sometimes commented on his dislike for this kind of commentarial "scholasticism" in philosophy, so it could be that there is no industry of Bunge studies in part because he himself discouraged it. He encouraged students to do original work on big problems, not to write commentaries on his past work. As a realist, Bunge was primarily interested in the scientific study of reality, not the exegetical study of texts. In his 2012 book *Evaluating Philosophies* he said (p. 17):

> For example, in philosophy it is easier to publish scholastic comments
> on comments, or even existentialist nonsense, than original ideas
> about important but neglected problems.

Later in the same book, when commenting on Marxism, he disapprovingly said of philosophers who write in an imprecise way that is open to multiple interpretations (p. 90):

> This is the great advantage of ambiguity: it lends itself to multiple
> readings, hence to endless scholastic disputation.

Bunge didn't invite "endless scholastic disputation" about his work. Incidentally, Bunge even pointed to this as a flaw among some Popperians, the followers of Karl Popper. In his introduction to the 1999 republication of the edited collection *Critical Approaches to Science & Philosophy*, Bunge said of Popperians (p. vii):

> Imprecision and unsystematicity always breed multiple interpretations,
> which in turn breed unending disputes. No wonder that his followers
> are divided on many important points of exegesis.

Heinz Droste, in his chapter "Mario Bunge as a Public Intellectual" in the book *Mario Bunge: A Centenary Festschrift*, noted that there are no Bungeans analogous to the way that there are Popperians (p. 69):

> Bunge doesn't command an intervention force for critical cases of
> discussion like the Popperians do. In fact, it is doubtful that he
> would accept any form of proxy.

Droste also said (p. 71):

> Andreas Pickel suspects that Mario Bunge did not achieve high public
> recognition because he did not build something like a philosopher's
> school. But the reasons might lay deeper. Mario Bunge's concept of
> public recognition seems to follow a clearly different concept of
> publicity, in comparison to those journalistic interventions being
> used to promote the "public philosophers" Habermas and Kant. ... Bunge
> does not use "communications campaigns" to make his philosophy known.

As Droste suggested, Bunge was not very interested in self-marketing. Droste also said much else in his chapter that is relevant.

[A previous answer to this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/78334) suggested that Bunge is not more frequently referred to because of his character defects. I have never met Bunge, but I conclude from reading Bunge's works that this extremely negative appraisal is too harsh. I find Bunge's writings to be often charming and funny, and there are videos of him teaching that show him making students laugh, so his humor was not limited to his written texts. An article by Michael R. Matthews, who knew Bunge well over the last decades of Bunge's life, gave a more balanced portrayal of his character; he wrote (in "Mario Bunge: a Long and Productive Life", *Science & Education*, 25, 2016, pp. 1147–1148):

> In matters of academic debate, Bunge believes the argument should be
> stated as clearly and exactly as possible; and stated whenever
> warranted; lights should not be kept under bushels, and spades should
> be called spades. He has no regard for "soft-focus" writing or
> argument. Instead of saying "It could be thought that there is a
> weakness in your argument," he prefers the more direct "Your argument
> is weak." Instead of warm and pleasant agreement about claims that
> cannot be tested, he seeks clear, specific hypotheses that can be
> tested against evidence. Bunge here violates some scholars'
> understandings of academic "good manners." Between the rise of
> postmodernist conceptual incoherence and rightful concerns about
> giving offence, the promotion of direct and clear academic writing
> struggles at the present time; indeed, it is positively discouraged in
> numerous quarters where even correction of student writing is thought
> to be a dubious practice.
>
> In personal dealings, Bunge is polite, attentive, and concerned with
> the well-being of those about him. Office staff in the School of
> Education at UNSW where he spent a semester's leave in 2001 said he
> was the most polite, considerate, and courteous visitor that the
> school had ever had. Such estimations are, of course, usually not part
> of the public record. So, it is the learned but combative Bunge that
> the scholarly community knows. His style has had its professional
> price; it probably provides some explanation for why his wide-ranging
> and informed corpus of work has not been as engaged with as one might
> expect.

There is much more to say in answer to this question, but I hope this answer provides some clues about the reception of Mario Bunge's work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the answer here:
Mario Bunge (1919–2020): Physicist, philosopher, champion of science,
and citizen of the world
Michael Robert Matthews
Bunge was apparently a rather vain, infatuated and disrispectful person. Quote:
Still remembered by many who were present, in 1978 there was
the occasion of Bunge’s outspokenness at the International
Congress of Philosophy held in Düsseldorf, Germany. Sir John
Eccles, the Nobel-Prize winning Australian neurophysiologist, who
collaborated with Karl Popper in articulating a dualist but
interactionist theory of mind, gave the opening plenary address.
But instead of according the newly-minted Nobel Laureate the
expected, customary deference, Bunge, who was in the audience,
stood up and accused Eccles (and Popper) of philosophical
incoherence and of retarding the scientific study of mind. Many
philosophers, including those who agreed with Bunge’s views,
thought that it was not the occasion for the arguments to be aired.
Bunge thought differently; he had a different style.

Comment: MCR claimed in this answer that "Bunge was apparently a rather vain, infatuated and disrespectful person", but did not provide sufficient support for this claim. See the more balanced appraisal from M.R. Matthews in my answer: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/78741

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there is a project that revolves around the work of Bunge. [***Mɛtascience***](https://metascience-en.sopromet.org/sections/1-issues/number-1/) is a recent journal that attempts to develop a metascience, a scientific general discourse, from Bunge's thought. The journal is available in paper format from [**Éditions Matériologiques**](https://materiologiques.com/en/mtascience-discours-general-scientifique/298-mario-bunge-penseur-de-la-materialite-9782373612325.html) (in French), but texts in English are available free of charge on the ***Mɛtascience*** website.

Big Mac said above :

> As a realist, Bunge was primarily interested in the scientific study
> of reality, not the exegetical study of texts.

Which is totally true. This is so true that for us Bunge is no longer a philosopher, but a metascientist. For example, his ontology does not postulate any entity, since it takes for granted the existence of concrete objects postulated by the sciences, and its approach does not use any philosophical tool or method. For more on this, you can read the journal's manifesto, [***Metascience. For a Scientific General Discourse***](https://metascience-en.sopromet.org/metascience-for-a-scientific-general-discourse/), published in the first issue, and a draft of its sequel for the second issue, [***What is Metascientific Ontology?***](https://metascience-en.sopromet.org/what-is-metascientific-ontology/).

I'll quote Joseph Agassi, a good friend of Bunge, who sums up Bunge's approach well:

> The idea behind the [Bungean] program is as commonsense as could be.
> This may sound disappointing, as it lacks all extravagance, but then
> this is what the program is all about. The idea is to stay well within
> one world [...]. (in *Ontology and its discontent*)

Comment: Your project is interesting! For an English speaker your choice of the word _metascience_ is unfortunate since it is already used with a different meaning: see [Metascience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metascience). There's no corresponding metascience article in the French Wikipedia, which suggests the term is not used in French with the same meaning. Your project seems aimed at the Francophone intellectual milieu, which is good, but less relevant in English. In English, the term _scientific philosophy_ (for example), which Bunge himself and others used, makes more sense.